# Doubt in android Activity navigation

Tags: android

In my application, the first activity takes care of the splash screen/loader and onces it completes the load, a second activity comes up or starts.. Now when a person clicks on back or navigates back, it is supposed to exit the application but it goes tthe loader or splash activity..how can i avoid this ?? Hope my question was clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application opens second screen aka second activity finish the first activity aka splash screen.

Just use `finish()` method to achieve this.

Here is an example

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context, Second.class);         
startActivity(intent );
//call finish 
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you start second activity after then CurrentActivity.finish() current activity in your case like splash...